# Filtering two columns using Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a filter to update a column and it works. But now I need to create 2 filters inside the same cell.

Filter 1

```
=FILTER(ABD!C:C,ABD!K:K="Ok",ABD!J:J="Catarina Ferreira")
```

Filter 2

```
=FILTER(MM!E:E,MM!L:L="Ok",MM!K:K="Catarina Ferreira")
```

I need both filters to work inside the same cell. Is it possible?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MKXCAc1-d8OU008OEHI2Tu7AObvaOueUD30jl5iG6W8/edit#gid=1288067300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(FILTER({ABD!C:C; MM!E:E}, {ABD!K:K; MM!L:L}="Ok", 
                                {ABD!J:J; MM!K:K}="Catarina Ferreira"))
```